# two same commands results in different respond in git

Tags: git, version-control

I am now studying git, and I just encountered a confusing problem: I used two same series of commands but the results shown differently. The first series of commands are:

```
lihangdeMacBook-Pro:learngit lihang$ git checkout -b dev

Switched to a new branch 'dev'

lihangdeMacBook-Pro:learngit lihang$ emacs readme.txt     //doing some editing 

lihangdeMacBook-Pro:learngit lihang$ git add readme.txt

lihangdeMacBook-Pro:learngit lihang$ git commit -m "branch test"

[dev 01d10cf] branch test

 1 file changed, 1 insertion(+)

lihangdeMacBook-Pro:learngit lihang$ git checkout master

Switched to branch 'master'

Your branch is up-to-date with 'origin/master'.
```

here the last sentence shows that "Your branch is up-to-date with 'origin/master'". 
Then I delete dev branch and start a new branch named feature 1:

```
lihangdeMacBook-Pro:learngit lihang$ git checkout -b feature1

Switched to a new branch 'feature1'

lihangdeMacBook-Pro:learngit lihang$ emacs readme.txt      //doing some editing

lihangdeMacBook-Pro:learngit lihang$ git add readme.txt

lihangdeMacBook-Pro:learngit lihang$ git commit -m "AND simple"

[feature1 4ad475a] AND simple

 1 file changed, 1 insertion(+), 1 deletion(-)

lihangdeMacBook-Pro:learngit lihang$ git checkout master

Switched to branch 'master'
Your branch is ahead of 'origin/master' by 1 commit.
  (use "git push" to publish your local commits)
```

the two series of commands are the same, but why the last sentence of the two commands shows different results?

Answer (score 0):

The output line `Your branch is` at the end of each statement is unrelated to the commands that you show (it's just providing you context about the state of the branch you just switched to). What it suggests is that before the second set of commands you did something which updated `master`, but you didn't push those changes to `origin`.

Comment: Thank you! it seems that master is different from origin...ummm... I'll figure this out.